# std::chrono::system_clock and C time

Tags: c++, c++-chrono

I am using the following time point definition universally in my project:

```
using time_point = std::chrono::time_point<std::chrono::system_clock, std::chrono::duration<long, std::ratio<1,1000>>>
```

With this definition I get a reasonable tradeoff between precision and range, unfortunately the default with nanosecond resolution gives me a too short range.

Unfortunately it seems I can not use the `chrono::system_clock::from_time_t()` and `chrono::system_clock::to_time_t` functions to convert between `std::time_t` and the time point with non default resolution. Is there a way I can use the `to_time_t` and `from_time_t` functions with "my" time_point class?

Comment: Nano seconds with a signed 64 bit number works up to 2262 assuming a 1970 epoch, isn't that sufficient?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you assume that `std::chrono::system_clock` has the same epoch as `time_t` (it usually does) then `to_time_t` and `from_time_t` are essentially just a `std::duration_cast`.

For example this code should print the same values twice (note that whether `to_time_t` rounds or truncates is unspecified and `duration_cast` always truncates so there might be a 1 second difference):

```
const auto now = std::chrono::system_clock::now();
time_t time = std::chrono::system_clock::to_time_t(now);
std::cout << time << "\n";
std::cout << std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::seconds>(now.time_since_epoch()).count() << "\n";
std::cout << std::chrono::system_clock::from_time_t(time).time_since_epoch().count() << "\n";
std::cout << std::chrono::system_clock::time_point(std::chrono::seconds(time)).time_since_epoch().count() << "\n";
```

You can therefore write your own to/from_time_t functions fairly easily:

```
constexpr time_point  my_point_from_time_t(time_t value)
{
    return time_point(std::chrono::seconds(value));
}

constexpr time_t my_point_to_time_t(const time_point & value)
{
    return std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::seconds>(value.time_since_epoch()).count();
}
```

If `system_clock` doesn't use the same epoch as `time_t` then you can simply adjust the values:

```
const time_t system_clock_epoch = std::chrono::system_clock::to_time_t({});

time_point  my_point_from_time_t(time_t value)
{
    return time_point(std::chrono::seconds(value - system_clock_epoch));
}

time_t my_point_to_time_t(const time_point & value)
{
    return std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::seconds>(value.time_since_epoch()).count() + system_clock_epoch;
}
```

Comment: Fortunately, `std::chrono::system_clock` will be mandated to use the Unix epoch, in the C++20 standard. But the epoch and resolution of `std::time_t` is still unspecified. In POSIX-compliant systems (and in MSVC), `std::time_t` counts seconds since the Unix epoch. Thus, since C++20, the epochs can differ on non-POSIX systems only. So, by assuming that `std::time_t` might not use the Unix epoch, you would already assume the system not being POSIX-compliant. That's fine, but in that case, there is no guarantee that `std::time_t` uses seconds (and not milliseconds or whatever) on such a system.